Why is ReactPDF.renderToBuffer not a function in @react-pdf/renderer?
I’m trying to generate a PDF using @react-pdf/renderer, and I want to directly render the PDF to a Buffer for further processing (e.g., saving it to a file or sending it as an HTTP response). However, when I call ReactPDF.renderToBuffer, I get the following error:
TypeError: _react_pdf_renderer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.renderToBuffer is not a function

Used the following code to generate the PDF:
const buffer = await ReactPDF.renderToBuffer(<MyDocument />);


can you try to import it like this import { renderToBuffer } from "@react-pdf/renderer"

That function exist as @mocherfaoui mentioned however isn't mentioned in the documentation for some reason. Until this is fixed you can do:
const pdfInstance = ReactPDF.pdf(<MyDocument />);
const buffer = await pdfInstance.toBuffer();


the renderToBuffer function exists, see here. it's re-exported as a named export and there is no mention of it in the documentation which is confusing. I think this will be fixed in a future update.

thank you for mentioning this it seems weird I added your info in the answer.

I'll just leave it here, maybe you'll find it helpful.
Environment
OS: MacOS
Browser: Chrome
Next.js : 14.2.10
React-pdf version : 4.1.5
The task is to generate a pdf on the server and send it in an HTTP response.
Error I encountered
Error: I.Component is not a constructor
The code I used is in the route.ts file.

        /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
    
    import InvoicePdfTemplate from '@/components/Template'
    import { renderToBuffer } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
    import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server'
    
    export async function POST (request: NextRequest): Promise<Response> {
      try {
        const body = await request.json()
        const pdfBuffer = await renderToBuffer(Template({ data: body }) as React.ReactElement)
    
        return new Response(pdfBuffer, {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=invoice_${body.invoice_number}.pdf`
          }
        })
      } catch (error: any) {
        return new Response(`Error: ${error.message}`, {
          status: 400
        })
      }
    }


The solution that helped me ( GitHub - https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2350#issuecomment-1914234934 )
Add to the configuration file next.config.js
     const nextConfig = {
          experimental: {
            serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@react-pdf/renderer'],
          }
        };

